# Installed Windows 7 on a recovery partition

Tags: windows-7

I accidentally installed Windows 7 on a recovery partition.  Now please tell me what should I do, as there is less space on that partition.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Windows on the correct partition, I think trying to migrate will take you longer than a clean install

As what to do with the recovery partition, you might be able to "recover" it from within your previous OS or by using a recovery disk to create one

*Any other tips to create a recovery partition, without involving creating your own version of Windows using BartPE would probably of help to Sam*

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just copy recovery related files to a new partition?

You can then expand the "recovery" partition with Windows on to a larger size.

(You may need to move partitions around so recovery is at the front; this would depend on how your recovery partition is set up)